# Alert when device has no connection

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, reachability

If the user is not connected to the Internet, I would like to display an alert. How would I do this?

Comment: This is iOS. I know how to make an alert come up, but I only want  it to come up if the device isn't connected to wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Apple's [Reachability sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) and use the Reachability classes to test for connection status.